# Slideshow with touchscreen support

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm creating a website and I would to add a slideshow that works also with touchscreen on smartphones and tablets.
Could you suggest me some modules that do it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've found this: [Flex Slider](http://drupal.org/project/flexslider), this seems works on my android smartphone